# SwiftUI Navigation Reset when sidebar update

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, navigation, sidebar

Change the state in SideBar will reset the navigation

I wish to use my saved data as selection in Sidebar, but when I try to add data to core data, the sidebar will reset state and take me back to root navigation. Is it possible to hold the state of navigation?
[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Add Item") {
                    AddItemView()
                }
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
}

struct AddItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("nav to next") {
            AddItemDetailView()
        }
    }
}

struct AddItemDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    var body: some View {
        Button("add") {
            addItem()
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [NavigationStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack) instead of NavigationView. See also [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one level of detail `NavigationLink`s so you can set your `AddItemView`'s link to not be detail as follows:

```
        NavigationLink("nav to next") {
            AddItemDetailView()
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
```